# i used FROM_geojson() to get data but letters are broken

Tags: r, url, geojson

I used FROM_geojson() to get geojson data from url.
The context contains korean language and i set default encoding in Rstudio global option as "UTF-18".
But context are broken like  "湲몄뙂怨듭썝" which should be presented like "길쌈공원".
Do you have any idea to solve this problem?
(I'm not sure if it's encoding problem.. )

```
url="https://icloudgis.incheon.go.kr/server/rest/services/ParkScore_Dynamic/MapServer/1/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1&f=geojson"
file_json=FROM_GeoJson(url_file_string = url)
```

Comment: does `sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(url)` work for you?